# ошибки в проектировании базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть база данных написанная на MySQL, мне сказали исправить ошибки в ней "дублирование информации в БД и присутствуют одинаковые сущности", но я не понимаю где и как.
Вот код для БД:

```sql
drop 
  database if exists operator;
create database operator;

use operator;

create table clientLegal(
  id_cL int primary key, 
  companyName varchar(45), 
  inn varchar(30), 
  legalAddres varchar(50), 
  actualAddres varchar(50)
);

create table clientIndividual(
  id_cI int primary key, 
  firstName varchar(20), 
  lastName varchar(20), 
  middleName varchar(20), 
  birthDate date, 
  passportNumber varchar(10), 
  city varchar(20)
);

create table manager(
  id_M int primary key, 
  managerName varchar(20)
);

create table contract(
  id_ct int primary key, contractNumber int, 
  contractDate date
);

create table tAccount(
  id_tA int primary key, accountNumber int
);

create table payments(
  id_pm int primary key, 
  paymentDate date, 
  amount int, 
  tA_id int, 
  foreign key(tA_id) references tAccount(id_tA)
);

create table tClient(
  id_tC int primary key, 
  ct_id int, 
  tA_id int, 
  cI_id int, 
  cL_id int, 
  foreign key(cI_id) references clientIndividual(id_cI), 
  foreign key(cL_id) references clientLegal(id_cL), 
  foreign key(ct_id) references contract(id_ct), 
  foreign key(tA_id) references tAccount(id_tA)
);

create table managerServices(
  id_mS int primary key, 
  servicesPrice int, 
  pdate date, 
  tC_id int, 
  M_id int, 
  foreign key(tC_id) references tClient(id_tC), 
  foreign key(M_id) references manager(id_M)
);

create table tCall(
  id_tC int primary key, 
  cType enum(
    'Другой', 'Междугородний', 
    'Международный'
  ), 
  cPrice int
);

create table message(
  id_me int primary key, 
  mType enum(
    'Другой', 'Междугороднее', 
    'Международное'
  ), 
  mPrice int
);

create table tariff(
  id_tf int primary key, 
  tariffName varchar(20), 
  subscriptionFee int, 
  callMinutes int, 
  SMS int
);

create table tCTf(
  id_tCTf int primary key, 
  tf_id int, 
  tc_id int, 
  foreign key(tf_id) references tariff(id_tf), 
  foreign key(tc_id) references tCall(id_tC)
);

create table meTf(
  id_meTf int primary key, 
  tf_id int, 
  me_id int, 
  foreign key(tf_id) references tariff(id_tf), 
  foreign key(me_id) references message(id_me)
);

create table phoneNumber(
  id_pN int primary key, 
  countryCode varchar(4), 
  cityCode varchar(3), 
  clientPhoneNumber varchar(7), 
  tC_id int, 
  foreign key(tC_id) references tClient(id_tC)
);

create table tariffServices(
  id_tS int primary key, 
  tf_id int, 
  pN_id int, 
  pDate date, 
  foreign key(pN_id) references phoneNumber(id_pN), 
  foreign key(tf_id) references tariff(id_tf)
);

create table outCallsPhoneNumber(
  id_oN int primary key, 
  countryCode varchar(4), 
  cityCode varchar(3), 
  clientPhoneNumber varchar(7)
);

create table callJournal(
  id_cJ int primary key, 
  pN_id int, 
  oN_id int, 
  dtStart datetime, 
  dtEnd datetime, 
  foreign key(pN_id) references phoneNumber(id_pN), 
  foreign key(oN_id) references outCallsPhoneNumber(id_oN)
);

create table outSMSPhoneNumber(
  id_oN int primary key, 
  countryCode varchar(4), 
  cityCode varchar(3), 
  clientPhoneNumber varchar(7)
);

create table smsJournal(
  id_sJ int primary key, 
  pN_id int, 
  oN_id int, 
  dtOut datetime, 
  dtIn datetime, 
  foreign key(pN_id) references phoneNumber(id_pN), 
  foreign key(oN_id) references outSMSPhoneNumber(id_oN)
);
```

Таблица clientLegal хранит информацию о клиентах юр лицах,
clientIndividual информаицию о физ. лицах,таблица tClient это "общий клиент", у клиента есть контракт, информация о котором содержится в таблице contract, у него также есть счет - таблица tAccount, она связана с таблицей payments, в который хранится информация о платежах, у клиентов может быть персональный менеджер, информация о менеджерах хранится в таблице manager, а подключении услуги персонального менеджера информацию содержит таблица managerServices. У клиентов есть телефонные номера они содержатся в таблице phoneNumber, по каждому номеру ведется учет смс и звонков, в таблице smsJournal и callJournal соответственно, информация о номерах, на которые совершаются звонки и смс содержится в таблицах outCallsPhoneNumber и outCallsPhoneNumber (выглядит очень костыльно, но ничего лучше без цикличности в бд я не придумал), у номеров телефонов есть тариф, таблица с информациией о подключении тарифа - tariffServices, информация о самих тарифах содержится в tariff, с таблицой tariff связаны таблицы tcall и message через таблицы tctf и metf соответственно (чтобы избежать связи много ко многим).

Задача была в том, чтобы спроектировать базу данных по предметной области: "Компания-оператор мобильной телефонной связи обслуживает частных и корпоративных клиентов. Для каждого вида клиентов существуют общие атрибуты (номер контракта, дата заключения, номер счета и т.д.) и индивидуальные атрибуты. Например, для частных лиц это: ФИО, адрес, дата рождения, паспортные данные и т.д.; для юридических лиц: наименование, ИНН, юридический и фактический адрес и т.д.  К каждому из клиентов может относиться от одного до неограниченного количества телефонных номеров. Каждому номеру должен соответствовать один из тарифных планов. Тарифные планы могут отличаться между собой разной стоимостью абонентской платы за месяц и ценой одной минуты разговора в зависимости от следующих параметров: тип звонка (входящий/исходящий), продолжительность одного разговора, количество минут от начала учетного периода (месяц или день), внутрисетевой звонок, звонок на номер другого оператора, междугородний звонок, международный звонок. Кроме того, аналогичным образом задается стоимость одного короткого сообщения SMS по следующим параметрам: тип сообщения (входящее/исходящее), общее количество сообщений с начала учетного периода, сообщение внутри сети, сообщение на номер другого оператора, междугороднее или международное сообщение. Для каждого номера необходимо регистрировать журнал совершенных разговоров и отправленных/полученных сообщений. В журнале отмечается тип звонка, дата и время начала, продолжительность, номер абонента, с которым происходило соединение (то же самое для сообщений). При этом по начальным цифрам номера, с которым происходило соединения, необходимо определить тип звонка (внутрисетевой, на номер другого оператора, междугородний или международный). В компании предоставляется услуга персонального менеджера для клиентов. Для этого ведется учет менеджеров и каждому клиенту может быть предоставлен за дополнительную плату один персональный менеджер. Кроме того, в качестве дополнительной услуги по определенным номерам может быть предоставлена услуга справочного бюро. Для каждого клиента необходимо учитывать совершенные платежи."

А проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно исправить дублирование информации и то, что в базе есть одинаковые сущности, но я даже не понимаю где(

Ну и также приложу схему БД
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну как минимум таблицы с телефонами и таблицы с журналами можно объединить

Comment: у вас буквы платные? как вы через год будете вспоминать, что такое ct_id, чем оно отличается от ci_id или cl_id и не опечатка ли это в запросе вообще?

Comment: Поясните за что отвечают каждая таблица и общий контекст задачи.

Comment: @РусланМамедов поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы добавил дополнительно таблицы country, city, company, address, person.

Все таблицы, которые хранят в себе телефон строкой сделал бы ссылку на таблицу phone (это название мне больше нравится, т.к кроме номера можно хранить еще дополнительную информацию, которая с ним связана).

Сама таблица с телефонами должна быть одна, чтобы не дублировать информацию несколько раз. Все идентификаторы назвал бы просто id. А ссылающиеся ключи по следующему паттерну: <имя_сущности>_id, например phone_id. Из названия таблиц убрал бы префикс t - вы же базу данных проектируете и так понятно, что это таблица. Вообще старайтесь поменьше использовать сокращения - сейчас буквы бесплатные и мониторы широкие.

P.S немного не понял насчет sms и calls. Но я бы просто создал таблицы(smsJournal & callJournal) и туда все записывал.

Comment: А разве можно убирать таблицы outCallsPhoneNumber  и outSMSPhoneNumber, тогда же придется в журнале звонков и сообщений делать два FK на один атрибут (id в таблице phone) и получится цикличность в БД? Или я чего-то не понимаю...

Comment: Это будет не цикличность в бд, а вполне нормальная практика. Айдишники телефонов будут же разные. Один будет отвечать за того кто позвонил, а другой - кому позвонил. Это совершенно нормально.